# How to find $f(x,y) = f(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)) $?

Tags: integration, dynamical-systems, average

How to find $f(x,y) = f(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)) $ ?

Notice that Gauss found the case $f_1 =( x + y)/2 , f_2 =( xy )^ {1/2}$. The socalled AGM.
He even had an integral representation for it.

Even fractional iterations are possible

See

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic–geometric_mean

And

http://planetmath.org/convergenceofarithmeticgeometricmean/

Where the ratio is useful.

I have no idea how he came Up with the integral.

How to generalise the integral ?

How to handle the generalizations ?

Say i accept integrals and Abel funtions and inverse Abel functions, can i express it then ?

To clarify :

See : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation

Where the Abel function is a solution to the Abel equation.

Also

The inverse Abel function =  superfunction

See : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfunction

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Made an edit with Some links, look at them ! I hope that helps @socrates